# list in SML Language

Tags: list, sml

I'm new to SML and I'm trying to run some code from github in SML/NJ. I'm currently trying to call the function

```ml
fun dates_in_month(xs : (int * int * int) list, n : int) =
  if null xs then 
    []
  else if #2 (hd xs) = n then 
    (hd xs)::dates_in_month(tl xs, n)
  else
    dates_in_month(tl xs, n)
```

like so

```ml
dates_in_month(3::2::1::nil, 5)
```

but I get the following error message on SML/NJ 110.97

```
stdIn:8.1-8.31 Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload - bad instantiation]
  operator domain: (int * int * int) list * int
  operand:         'Z[INT] list * 'Y[INT]
  in expression:
    dates_in_month (3 :: 2 :: <exp> :: <exp>, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises because you're currently trying to call a function of type `(int * int * int) list * int -> (int * int * int) list` with a parameter of type `int list * int`. That is to say, the first element of your tuple is of the incorrect type.

You instead want a list of 3-tuples of `int`. You could construct one like so:

```ml
(1, 2, 3) :: (4, 5, 6) :: nil
```

or a bit briefer as

```ml
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Note that here the elements of the list are 3-tuples of `int` as opposed to just `int`s like you had previously.

Answer (score 0):

The type `(int * int * int) list` refers to something that looks like:

```
[(1,2,3), (-69,0,69), (10,100,1000)]
```

What you are currently passing to the function is:

```
[3,2,1]
```

This is because the operator `::` is used to construct lists, which are DISTINCT from tuples like (1,2,3). (Basically, a variable of type `list` can be of any length, whereas a tuple is of a fixed length).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the closest approach to you function:

```
fun dates_in_month(xs : (int * int * int) list, n : int) =
    if (null xs) then 
        []
      else if #2(hd xs) = n then 
        (hd xs)::dates_in_month(tl xs, n)
      else
        dates_in_month(tl xs, n);
```

I'll explain the syntax:

We have the function signature

```
fun dates_in_month(xs : (int * int * int) list, n : int)
```

which means that we declare on a new bind in our environment which is binding between the value dates_in_month and the function itself
which takes two params (xs, n), their types could be indicated, but actually in sml we have type inference, so it is unneccesary to indicate it but you can.

Next we have:

```
if (null xs) then 
        []
      else if #2(hd xs) = n then 
        (hd xs)::dates_in_month(tl xs, n)
      else
        dates_in_month(tl xs, n);
```

`if (null xs) then []` - regard to that I think you rather use pattern matching , which makes the code easier to read and understand.

```
 else if #2(hd xs) = n then 
        (hd xs)::dates_in_month(tl xs, n)
      else
        dates_in_month(tl xs, n);
```

This code go over xs list which is a list of tuples of 3, go over all elements and when tuple element have 2nd value equal to n it concatanates this tuple and check recursively all the other, otherwise if it doesn't equal to n, it doesn't concatanate it.

For instance:

`dates_in_month([(3,2,1)], 5);`

val it = []: (int * int * int) list;

`dates_in_month([(3,2,1)], 2);`

val it = [(3, 2, 1)]: (int * int * int) list;

`dates_in_month([3,2,1], 5);`

Error: Type clash

It would raise Type clash error because of mismatched types, because the list should be of tuples, also tuples of 3.

If you use attributes of sml like pattern matching, type inference, wildcard('_') you could write much shorter code like:

```
fun dates_in_month([],_)=[]
  | dates_in_month((x,y,z)::tl,n) = 
      if y=n then (x,y,z)::dates_in_month(tl, n)      
      else dates_in_month(tl, n);
```

Also you can use list operations to short that even more:

```
fun dates_in_month_list(xs,n) = List.filter (fn (_,y,_)=>(y=n)) xs;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?